# Removing copy ctor of 3rd party class

Tags: c++

I have a class that stores a large `std::map`. My understanding is that the idiomatic way to do this is:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(/* Note: passed by value */ std::map<Bar, Baz> large_map) : large_map_(std::move(large_map)) {}
 private:
  std::map<Bar, Baz> large_map_;
};

int main() {
  std::map<Bar, Baz> large_map;
  // Work hard to initialize large_map.
  Foo foo = Foo(std::move(large_map));
}
```

This transfers the ownership of large_map from main, to the constructor arg and then to Foo's member. The problem with this is that the code is hard to use properly and I discovered that someone somewhere created a `Foo` and forgot to move the map into the ctor:

```
void deep_dark_hidden_code() {
  std::map<Bar, Baz> large_map;
  // Work hard to initialize large_map.
  Foo foo = Foo(large_map); // Whoops! The author of this code forgot to std::move
}
```

I am looking for a way to write `Foo` which protects against such mistakes. My first thought was to use `unique_ptr`

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(std::unique_ptr<std::map<Bar, Baz>> large_map_ptr) : large_map_(std::move(*large_map_ptr)) {}
 private:
  std::map<Bar, Baz> large_map_;
};

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<std::map<Bar, Baz>> large_map_ptr = new std::map<Bar, Baz>;
  // Work hard to initialize large_map_ptr.
  Foo foo = Foo(std::move(large_map_ptr));
}
```

This code is essentially using `unique_ptr` as a hack to erase the copy constructor of `std::map`. My question is whether there is a more explicit way to do this. Some magic template `make_uncopyable` like:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(make_uncopyable<std::map<Bar, Baz>> large_map) : large_map_(std::move(large_map)) {}
 private:
  std::map<Bar, Baz> large_map_;
};
```

The desired effect is to leave the code in my `main` intact but prevent the code in `deep_dark_hidden_code` from compiling.

Comment: First of all you need to make sure that the compiler (with optimizations enabled) is actually copying that large map. If the map isn't used later in the function the compiler might as well elide the copying. Perhaps the compiler is smart enough that you don't have to spend time on this. :)

Comment: Change the constructor to accept a `std::map<Bar, Baz>&& large_map`. Then the compiler will not let you pass lvalue references

Comment: The title says `3rd party class`, but I can't see any 3-rd party dependency in your example. If you are free to change the definition of the class however you want, i can't see a problem with just removing/deleting any constructor which takes a `std::map<Bar, Baz>` by value

Comment: You could just wrap the 3rd party (`Foo`) class in your own (`MyFoo`) class and add `using Foo(...);` for the constructors, etc. you want and delete those (like copy) that you don't want.

Comment: The 3rd party class in question is `std::map` I would like to erase the copy c-tor of `std::map` but obviously can't change its code.

Comment: Cool! std::map&& worked. Is that the standard way to write ctor's? All args that we want to take ownership of should be passed as &&?

Comment: `Is that the standard way to write ctor's` as long as you want to accept **only** rvalues - yes. `All args that we want to take ownership of should be passed as &&` the "ownership" is not very precise term here. When an object is moved, it's moved. The client code is supposed to not use it after that, but technically it's still possible. There are compiler warning which can prevent you from doing so

Comment: What a move constructor actually does depends on your "third party" class, . In any way there are *two* objects involved here. Move semantics is not about the ownership of the objects themselves, but rather about the ownership of any deep resources they own (which in turn depends on how the move constructor is implemented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title appears to be a slight misnomer here (or is at least at odds with the contents with your question):

(At least in the example given), you do not want to remove the copy constructor i.e. `Foo::Foo(const Foo& other)`, but rather prevent invokation of `Foo`'s constructor with a non-movable argument.

As **Mestkon** pointed out (all credit to them - if they want to post it as an answer, just give me a yell and I'll remove mine), you could change `Foo`'s constructor to require a `std::map<Bar, Baz>&& large_map` i.e.

```
Foo(std::map<Bar, Baz>&& large_map) : large_map_(std::move(large_map)) {}
```

A test at Godbolt confirms that the compiler will refuse to accept the `Foo foo = Foo(large_map);` in the `deep_dark_hidden_code().`, demanding the argument to be movable (as desired). This this might still run the risk of others "fixing" their code by simply slapping a `std::move()` around their `large_map`... and then attempting to continue using it **after** constructing `Foo` with it.

If you want *really* want to prevent the invokation of the copy constructor (here `std::map`), things become rather difficult, as you cannot change the the definition std::map to erase its copy constructor. I don't feel I have a good answer to this.